# Increasing the speed of working with big csv files using Pandas in Python

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to download market data on every BTCUSD trade and store it in csv file using following code

```
from binance_f import RequestClient
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time


def download():

    request_client = RequestClient(api_key=x,
                                   secret_key=x)
    # Get info on latest 500 trades
    result = request_client.get_recent_trades_list(symbol="BTCUSDT", limit=500)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Price', 'Qty'])
    for i in range(len(result)):
        df = df.append({'Date': result[i].time, 'Price': result[i].price, 'Qty': result[i].qty}, ignore_index=True)
        df['Date'][i] = df['Date'][i] / 1000
        df['Date'][i] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df['Date'][i])
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df[['Price', 'Qty']] = df[['Price', 'Qty']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

    # Merge latest trades with existing file 
    old_df = pd.read_csv('btc_volumes')
    old_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(old_df['Date'])

    new_df=pd.concat([old_df,df]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    new_df.sort_values(by='Date')

    new_df.to_csv('btc_volumes',index=False)

while True:
    try:
        download()
        time.sleep(10) # 10 sec interval
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\n\nKeyboard exception received. Exiting.')
        exit()
```

As time passes, the size of csv file obviously grows in size and it takes longer time to execute the code (at 1.8M rows approximately 30 sec). Is there a way to increase the speed of the code and bring it down under 10-20 sec while working with files of 20-30MM rows?

Thanks!

Comment: Please test first what is the code that makes it so slow. Is it the concat?

Comment: And why you do the to_datetime conversion every time you open the old_df. It looks you don't need it

Comment: Hi, gtomer. For the first comment I hoped that someone with more extensive knowledge about Python than myself would point out on the element that makes it so slow and how to solve it. For the second comment - when reading csv, it reads Data columns as string.

Comment: Without the large data file it is hard to emulate.
See an answer below to track time

Answer (score 0):

To understand you problem better we need to understand which of the lines of code takes a long time.

add this at the top of the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

And add this "print time command" in various places in the code and run it again:

```
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

If the problem is with saving the CSV, save with chunks may help. Try this:

```
stage.to_csv('btc_volumes.csv', index=False, chunksize=100000)
```

Comment: It seems saving to csv takes most time:

Data donwload finished 14:10:26
Converted json into proper dataframe 14:10:28
Read csv file finished 14:10:29
Converted date column into proper format 14:10:30
Finished concatinating 14:10:30
Finished saving to csv 14:10:41

Comment: Great. Now you know where to focus. You can try writing the CSV with chunks. This should speed things up. See above updated answer

Comment: Also check the version of your Pandas - see if it is the latest

Comment: Thanks for help, but it still takes 10-12 sec to save to csv even with the chunks implemented as you suggested.

Comment: Try playing with the chunks value.
Another option, depends on your use-case: keep current month CSV & accumulated CSV and merge them at the end of every month.